# have_openssl and have_ssl changed to disabled

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

after i created prerequisite files for having connection with mysql using SSL with commands:

```
openssl genrsa 4096 > ca-key.pem 

openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -days 9999 -key ca-key.pem > ca-cert.pem  

openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -days 9999 -nodes -keyout server-key.pem > server-req.pem 

openssl x509 -req -in server-req.pem -days 9999 -CA ca-cert.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -set_serial 01 > server-cert.pem
```

i added this to /etc/mysql/my.cnf .

```
[mysqld]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/certs/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/certs/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/certs/server-key.pem
```

after this `have_openssl` and `have_ssl` from YES value becomes to DISABLED when i check the variables of mysql and SSL is disabled supposedly. what is the problem and how to fix this?